# Use NiFi "sensitive" parameters to generate JSON payload for HTTP authentication

Tags: apache-nifi

Using Apache Nifi v1.19.1, I need to make an HTTP `POST` request via the `InvokeHTTP` processor in order to authenticate with an API before I can upload the *FlowFile* via another `InvokeHTTP` processor.

I've configured the username/password for the API in a Parameter Context and marked them (as you might expect) as "Sensitive Value".

Now, when I try to reference those parameters in the `GenerateFlowFile` processor's `Custom Text` property, I get the error:

> 'Custom Text' is invalid because the property 'Custom Text' cannot reference Parameter 'username' because the Sensitivity of the parameter does not match the Sensitivity of the property.

(And again for the `password` parameter.) I understand why this is, but it seems like an interesting limitation. At some point I need to be able to utilize that username/password in my flow.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Any specific reason to have the username and password as part of the `GenerateFlowFile` processor and not using it directly within the `InvokeHTTP` by adding a new property and using the parameter context.

Comment: The username/password is sent in the body of the request as a JSON document. I didn't think I could do this directly within the `InvokeHTTP` processor -- can I?